# How to draw Wingdings 2 characters outside of the 0..255 range in .NET?

Tags: .net, gdi+

The standard windows Charmap utility shows quite a few characters in the "Wingdings 2" font whose character codes are greater than 255 - for example, 0xE4E shows a hand.

However, if I try to draw these characters as follows:

```
g.DrawString(new string((char) 0xE4E, 1), new Font("Wingdings 2", 20), brush, x, y);
```

then all I get is a standard "box" replacement character. This is weird, because the above code works for Wingdings 2 symbols between 0x21 and 0xFF, and also works for ALL symbols in, say, Arial Unicode MS.

How can I draw those characters from this particular font? Is there a separate API?

(Win7; .NET 3.5 SP1)

---

P.S. Here's the weird Character Map font with the duplicated character ranges:

[image: charmap]

Comment: instead of new string((char) 0xE4E try "\uABCD"

Comment: Something is wrong with font mapping on your machine, my guess.

Comment: @Jared: good point, but it's an int because I'm looping over the chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no special API, nor is the fonts special per se. Wingdings et al. just don't use the "expected" glyphs for the character codes

However, I don't see that character in Charmap with that character code for that font (Win 7). If you're thinking of the character I think you're thinking of, it's just 0x4E.

[Wingdings 2 in Character Map http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/5746/charmapwingdings2.png](http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/5746/charmapwingdings2.png)

Comment: Hmm... you're right, it's the same character. My charmap seems to be showing the very same set of characters three times, under different ranges! I'm on the 64-bit Win7 by the way.

Comment: @Earlz: Sorry. Had this been Meta, you would have had the chance to bask in the glory that is my freehand circles. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my CharMap (Vista), WinDings 2 only goes as far as 0xFF

So your code is good, you (char)codes are in doubt.

Comment: I just realized those extra pens at the end of my are the same ones as 0x21 and 0x22. I think something's gone wrong with the font in Win7, because those extra pens shouldn't actually be there - and neither should the repetitions in romkyns image.

Comment: Yes, and even if they are valid in Win7 or x64, you'd still want to use the below 0xFF codes for compatibility